# How to convert FileChannel object into file?

Tags: java, filechannel

I am getting below error:
ClassCastException: class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl cannot be cast to class java.io.File

Please help

Comment: Can you provide with some code with what you have already tried? also have a look at this https://www.baeldung.com/java-filechannel

Comment: Thanks. I tried to get a lock of file using FileChannel and later tried to update same file passing FileChannel . Now my writer class using file object, hence I need to cast FileChannel instance into File before passing. Due to security reason cannot post the code.

Comment: Any chance you can provide then a demo application? Create a new application reproducing the problem and post it